# Is there a way good way to measure the width of a string (in pixels when rendered) in Javascript/HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, dom

It seems like I could create an empty DOM element containing the string, set the opacity to zero, display it, and get then measure the width of the element, but that seems really hack-y.  I'm wondering if there's a better way.  Any ideas?

EDIT: I need the width in pixels when rendered to the screen, not the number of characters :)

Comment: Why would it be hacky? The advance of a string is the width of its bounding box when rendered. `<div>`s make great bounding boxes. I believe jQuery / jQuery UI does something similar to get the width and height of a hidden div.

Comment: I'm afraid that there is only the "hack-y" [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/118251/1011582) at the moment. But it is actually not that "hack-y" in the HTML/CSS/JS world :).

Comment: You could probably calculate it if you were using a fixed width typeset.  Otherwise, you have to do what you proposed.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean the pixel width? No, there's no easy way to predict that in Javascript without having the browser render it. It depends so much on what font the browser has chosen, font size (which could be affected by inheritance if set with percentage or em), letter spacing, element padding, etc ad nauseum.

Your proposed solution of rendering it in the browser, even with zero opacity or `visibility:hidden` (thanks commenters) is the best way I think.

Comment: I figured that with display: hidden it would return 0 for the width. Thanks!

Comment: Depends on the browser perhaps, but `display:none` works for me in Chrome - http://jsfiddle.net/sfUmJ/1/

Comment: @ChadOkere: try to use `visiblity: hidden`

Comment: `display: hidden` is actually incorrect, it should be `display: none`